# Check and modify format of variable in expect script

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am trying to verify that the format of a variable is a number and is at least 10 digits long with leading zeros, inside of an expect script.

In a bash script it would look something like this:

```
[[ "$var" != +([0-9]) ]] && echo "bad input" && exit
while [[ $(echo -n ${var} | wc -c) -lt 10 ]] ; do var="0${var}" ; done
```

For the following input:

> 16

I am trying to achieve the following output:

> 0000000016

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to check whether a variable has just digits is to use a regular expression. Expect's regular expressions are entirely up to the task:

```
if {![regexp {^\d+$} $var]} {
    puts "bad input"
    exit
}
```

Padding with zeroes is best done by formatting the value; if you know C's `printf()`, you'll recognize the format:

```
set var [format "%010d" $var]
```

Comment: The format could also be `format "%0*d" 10 $var`; a little longer, but a little clearer (well, maybe; format strings _are_ a bit of a black art!)

Comment: If you use a minimum interval of 10 digits (e.g. the expected input length to validate) then you won't need to pad it. Either the string will match, in which case padding to 10 digits has no effect; or it won't, in which case the padding is irrelevant for validation. --Format is definitely the right way to go, though, if you expect your match to be *less than* some maximum length, and need to coerce it.

Comment: @CodeGnome I'm just replicating what that shell code did (error out if the variable doesn't hold just digits, and at least one of them at that, and pad with zeroes on the left if less than 10 digits).

Comment: Understood. Part of the issue is that the question title, the first line of the question, and the code sample are not all asking the same things. That's why a variety of answers is good; it also benefits others who have similar, but not identical problems down the road.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the zeros before the number.

Answer (score 0):

Expect is actually just an extension of TCL, so you can use any facility that TCL provides. TCL is an unusual language, but it's not hard to do what you want.

```
# Set a test string.
set testvar 1234567890

# Store the match (if any) in matchvar.
regexp {\d{10,}} $testvar matchvar
puts $matchvar

# Test that matchvar holds an integer.
string is integer $matchvar
```

The [string is](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/string.html) command is relatively new, so you might have to rely on the return value of regexp if your TCL interpreter doesn't support it.

Comment: “Relatively new”? Relative to what, dirt? A quick check of the change log indicates that it arrived in 8.1.1, and has been around for way over a decade…

Comment: When using `string is` it's usually best to use the `-strict` option: `string is integer ""` returns true; `string is integer -strict ""` returns false.

Comment: Make sure you use anchors in your regular expression to test for all digits: `regexp {\d{10,} abc1234567890def` returns true

Comment: @glennjackman You make some good points for the general case, but try it: `regexp {\d{10,}} abc1234567890def matchvar` only stores the matched characters in *matchvar*, not the whole string that contains the match. It's a good-enough solution for the question as posed.

Comment: FWIW, I was going to give an RE very much like the ones in this question, but then I read the (ugly!) shell code more carefully; it verifies that it's got digits and pads out to 10 digits with zeroes.